# Large numbers are inferred as strings by pandas when read from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file *Pandas_float_test.csv* with the below content

```
C0
20180904115745000007000
```

When I read the file using `read_csv` like below,

```
with open(os.path.join('data','Pandas_float_test.csv')) as csv_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,header='infer', parse_dates=True)
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
    print(pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns False
    print(pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns False
    print(pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns True
    print(pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns string
```

I would expect pandas to infer the dtype as `float64`, however it infers it as string. Is this intended?

Also when I try to recreate the same without using `read_csv` like below,

```
d = {'C0': [20180904115745000007000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
print(pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns False
print(pd.api.types.is_integer_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns False
print(pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns True
print(pd.api.types.infer_dtype(df['C0'])) # returns integer
```

`is_integer_dtype` returns `False` but `infer_dtype` returns integer.

I'm using pandas 0.24.0.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas usually infers it as a "string".

That is because the biggest int data type is int64 which consist numbers from

int64   Integer (-9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807)

```
>>> 9223372036854775807 > 20180904115745000007000
False
```

Check out more from numpy documentation :: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.types.html

So for converting the object / or to explicitly specifying the column datatype you can use 'dtype' attribute of pandas.read_csv which takes a dictionary as input which consist of column name as key and its data type as value.

```
dtype_dict = {
    'C0': 'float'
}

>>> df = pd.read_csv("sc.csv", dtype=dtype_dict)
>>> df.head()
             C0
0  2.018090e+22
1  2.018090e+22
2  2.018090e+22
```

Comment: Yes as you have mentioned the number is too big to be an integer but small enough to be a float. Considering that pandas has a float dtype, I'm expecting pandas to infer it as a float or a numeric type atleast not a string.

Comment: @erohsikkishore that's why we have to explicitly specify it as float.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas methods `pandas.read_csv()` and `pandas.DataFrame()` both have the **dtype** argument.

> dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, optional
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}

So you can set the type directly when creating the dataframe. If you don't, pandas will almost always default to string.

```
d = {'C0': [20180904115745000007000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, dtype="float")
```

`df.dtypes` returns `C0: float64`

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of this but if the number is small ,read_csv infers it as an integer. And bigger numbers as float . It doesn't always default to string..

Comment: My use case is such that , I cannot provide a dtype while reading the file. So I have to rely on pandas read_csv inferring logic to give the right dtype so that I can do further operations on tht dataseries based on dtype.